# Как сравнить два массива по конкретному элементу?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть два массива:

```
arr1=[{"id":"628db816eca22c8ffbdb3262", "location": false, ...}]
arr2=[{"newId":"628db816eca22c8ffbdb3262", "item":"apple", ...}]
```

Как сравнить эти два массива по `id` и `newId` и несовпадения добавить в новый массив?

Comment: Сравнивайте не массивы, а эти самые "конкретные элементы".

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о том, что мы проверяем первый элемент arr1 с первым элементом arr2 и так далее, то вот такой вариант:

```
const arr1 = [
  { id: '628db816eca22c8ffbdb3262', location: false },
  { id: '34', location: false },
];
const arr2 = [
  { newId: '34', item: 'apple' },
  { newId: '2523', item: 'apple' },
];

const difference = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i].id !== arr2[i].newId) {
    difference.push([arr1[i], arr2[i]]);
  }
}
```

если нет, то уточните более подробно пожалуйста

Comment: Первый элемент из первого и второй из второго.

Суть в том, что первый массив это массив в бд с задачами, второй это массив полученный по api из доски с задачами. И мне нужно в бд добавить отсутствующие там задачи из второго массива.